# Response Time - NodeJS + Express

Tags: express, timeout

I have a little problem with my application.
My architecture:

- Angular 6 (front)
- NodeJS + Express + MongoDB (back)

There is a part, in my NodeJS application, that communicates with a REST API.

When an user clicks on button on the Angular WebSite, I send a request to Express.

In my Express application, I send another request to the API to retrieve information.

But this process takes a lot of time. My request timeout

What is the best solution to keep my process working after the Express reply has been sent?
Should I do otherwise?

Comment: Hi you need to be more explicit, could you share some code? E.g the specific endpoint code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is with timeout, you can increase the default timeout:

You may set the timeout either globally for entire server. Read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout):

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  //Server is running
});
server.timeout = 1000; //1000 is one second.
```

or just for specific route. Read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback):

```
app.post('/xxx', function (req, res) {
   req.setTimeout(500000);
});
```

You can also change the timeout for the other API request you are making. Read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
//Assuming you are using request module.
var options = {
    url:  'http://url',
    timeout: 120000
}

request(options, function(err, resp, body) {});
```